# Ktlint fails with Wildcard import (cannot be auto-corrected)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle, ktlint

When I run `gradlew ktlintCheck` it fails with a lot of

> Wildcard import (cannot be auto-corrected)

errors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a `.editorconfig` file on root level and add amongst others:

```
disabled_rules=no-wildcard-imports
```

Answer (score 1):

Came across this [ktlint-gradle issue](https://github.com/JLLeitschuh/ktlint-gradle/issues/267) where it discussed about support to be added to [ktlint-gradle](https://github.com/jlleitschuh/ktlint-gradle) for *--disabled_rules*. It eventually got included and a new cleaner way of disabling no-wildcard import check is as following.

```
ktlint {
    enableExperimentalRules.set(true)
    disabledRules.set(setOf("experimental:package-name", "no-wildcard-imports"))
}
```

FYI: Following [rationale](https://github.com/JLLeitschuh/ktlint-gradle/issues/267#issuecomment-526207347) made *--disabled_rules* support possible.